# TDA0161: software for simulation?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, simulation, software

In what simulation software can I run a circuit with a [TDA0161](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/stmicroelectronics_cd00000119-1204052.pdf) proximity detection IC?

Comment: no idea ... i would ask the manufacturer if there is a model available ... from that i would deduce which sofware to use

Comment: AFAIK that part is obsolete and the only thing I found is the application note for the eval board. It's also a quite simple circuit so I doubt there is some advantage in simulating it since the only useful tuning is done on the field depending on what you are sensing. I'd recommend to use another component, TI, Analog and Microchip for sure make something that could replace it

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those parts you cannot simulate with the proximity of a metal object whose's eddy current resistance if greater than R1, then squelches the oscillator as the oscillator loop gain drops below 1.

But if you designed the part you could with more details than are offered in the daasheet.  This requires a design spec and lab test to verify the sensitivity and repeatability of the results.